# NSDateFormatter not working... where am i wrong?

Tags: iphone, nsdateformatter

i'm trying to parse a date writte in UTC format. For example

```
NSString *o = @"2011-04-23$20:28:00Z";
```

Here's the code i'm using:

```
df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];        
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd$HH:mm:00Z"];

 NSLog(@"^%@^ => %@", o, [df stringFromDate:[df dateFromString:o]]);
```

it produces the logging

```
^2011-04-23$20:28:00Z^ => (null)
```

Where am i wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Z` symbol in a date format string specifies a field for the timezone, if you want to parse the literal "Z", you will need to escape it with a `'`: `yyyy-MM-dd$HH:mm:00'Z`.

Comment: Great! Thanks, did't know about that